# Laravel vue cors - выдает ошибку

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

Использую за основу этот проект: https://github.com/cretueusebiu/laravel-vue-spa 

Так вот через axios нужно получить в виде json данные с другого сайта. Прописываю так:

```
axios.get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json').then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            })
```

И получаю ошибку:

> from origin 'localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

Знаю, что в интернете у многих была подобная ошибка, но так и не нашел решение. Перебробывал кучу способов.

Подскажите, как можно исправить эту ошибку. Не понимаю, где именно нужно вписать http заголовки, чтобы заработало. 
 Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Это сообщение означает, что с того сайта на который ссылайтесь нет доступа из вне на данный `File.json`

Comment: Странно. На локалке подключил axios через cdn `<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>` и ваш код отработал нормально: статус 200, в консоли ответ. Возможно [здесь](https://github.com/cretueusebiu/laravel-vue-spa/blob/master/resources/js/plugins/axios.js) при добавлении заголовков что-то не нравится на сервере api coindesk.

Comment: Попробуйте сделать запрос не через `axios`, а через обычный `fetch`. Должно работать.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko , может подскажите. У меня как ни странно, вчера не работала, а сегодня эта ошибка не вылазит (как через axios, так и через fetch), и работает. Это как-то сайт получается мне разблокировал доступ?

Comment: Просто Луна была не в той фазе.